# OPC-UA read Node Value via web request

Tags: soap, opc, opc-ua

I would like to get a value of a node and maybe the display name from a OPC-UA server. 
Do a UPC-UA Servers have a way to access it via http-requests or is there an other easy way of accessing nodes?

Comment: have you taken a look at QuickOPC client sdk? I find it very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not like you're hoping.

OPC-UA does define a SOAP/XML based transport, but it's so complex that to use it you still need to be accessing the server with an OPC-UA client SDK. It's not some RESTful web service you can call and hope to deal with the response on your own.

So you need an OPC-UA client, at which point you may as well just use the standard TCP/Binary transport, because nobody really uses the SOAP/XML transport anyway.

What language are you using? There are a number of OPC-UA SDKs available these days...